# Relationships GraphQL

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, graphql, mongoose-schema, apollo-server

The second week I try to link two collections in the apollo-server-express / MongoDB / Mongoose / GraphQL stack, but I do not understand how. I found a similar lesson with the REST API, what I need is called Relationships. I need this, but in GraphQL

[watch video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FVn_wj1jLN0&index=7&list=PLSpJkDDmpFZ5rZ5-Aur9WRNsBDSUS-0B9)

How to add cars to the User?
I collected the test server, the code is here: https://github.com/gHashTag/test-graphql-server
Help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have cloned your project and implemented some code and here what I changed to make relationship works. Note, I just did a basic code without validation or advance dataloader just to make sure non-complexity. Hope it can help.

**src/graphql/resolvers/car-resolvers.js**

```
import Car from '../../models/Car'
import User from '../../models/User'

export default {
  getCar: (_, { _id }) => Car.findById(_id),
  getCars: () => Car.find({}),
  getCarsByUser: (user, {}) =>  Car.find({seller: user._id }), // for relationship
  createCar: async (_, args) => {
    // Create new car
    return await Car.create(args) 
  }
}
```

**src/graphql/resolvers/user-resolvers.js**

```
import User from '../../models/User'

export default { 
  getUser: (_, { _id }) => User.findById(_id),
  getUsers: () => User.find({}),
  getUserByCar: (car, args) => User.findById(car.seller), // for relationship
  createUser: (_, args) => {
    return User.create(args) 
  }
}
```

**src/graphql/resolvers/index.js**

```
import UserResolvers from './user-resolvers'
import CarResolvers from './car-resolvers'

export default {
  User:{
    cars: CarResolvers.getCarsByUser  // tricky part to link query relation ship between User and Car
  },
  Car:{
    seller: UserResolvers.getUserByCar  // tricky part to link query relation ship between User and Car
  },
  Query: {
    getUser: UserResolvers.getUser,
    getUsers: UserResolvers.getUsers,
    getCar: CarResolvers.getCar,
    getCars: CarResolvers.getCars
  },

  Mutation: {
    createUser: UserResolvers.createUser,
    createCar: CarResolvers.createCar,
  }
}
```

**src/graphql/schema.js**

```
export default`
  type Status {
    message: String!
  }

  type User {
    _id: ID!
    firstName: String
    lastName: String
    email: String
    cars: [Car]
  }

  type Car {
    _id: ID 
    make: String
    model: String
    year: String
    seller: User
  }

  type Query {
    getUser(_id: ID!): User 
    getUsers: [User] 
    getCar(_id: ID!): Car 
    getCars: [Car] 
  }

  type Mutation {
    createUser(firstName: String, lastName: String, email: String): User 
    // change from _id to seller, due to base on logic _id conflict with CarId 
    createCar(seller: ID!, make: String, model: String, year: String): Car 
  }

  schema {
    query: Query
    mutation: Mutation
  }
`
```

**src/middlewares.js**

```
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import { graphqlExpress, graphiqlExpress } from 'apollo-server-express'
import { makeExecutableSchema } from 'graphql-tools'

import typeDefs from '../graphql/schema'
import resolvers from '../graphql/resolvers'
import constants from './constants'

export const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers
})

export default app => {

  app.use('/graphiql', graphiqlExpress({
    endpointURL: constants.GRAPHQL_PATH
  }))

  app.use(
    constants.GRAPHQL_PATH, 
    bodyParser.json(),
    graphqlExpress(req => ({
      schema,
      context: {
        event: req.event
      }
    }))
  )
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, the table understands with one-to-many communication, but how to make the connection many to many?

Answer (score 0):

try to make something like this in your car resolver

```
export default {
  getCar: ({ _id: ownId }, { _id }) =>
    Car.findById(ownId || _id);
// here is the rest of your code
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a resolver for the `cars` field on the User type.

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    getUsers: ...
    getCars: ...
    ...
  },
  Mutation: {
    ...
  },
  User: {
    cars: ...
  }
}
```